# Excel templates create two documents

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Double clicking on an Excel template called `Template.xltx` (or right click + new) should create a new file `Template1.xlsx`. This has been the case until about a week ago, but things have recently changed.

Now creating a new file from a template when Excel is closed:

- starts Excel
- creates `Template1.xlsx`
- creates `Template2.xlsx`
- sets the focus back to `Template1.xlsx`

Creating a new file from the same template again:

- creates `Template3.xlsx`
- sets the focus back to `Template1.xlsx`

It does it with old templates that worked for years and it does it with a brand new empty document saved as template. It does it with both macro enabled and standard templates.

Is this a problem with a recent Microsoft Update?

I am using Office 365 Business version 1708 build 8431.2079 click to run.

**EDIT**

We are using Office 32 bit.

The last updates installed around September 12 are:

- KB4038788 on 9/12
- KB4038806 on 9/12
- KB4034674 on 8/9
- KB4034662 on 8/8

I Asked to users who create dozens of new documents from my templates, they all say it started earlier this week. I asked if it started around September 12, they are sure it didn't start that long ago. They all had the same updates as me, some on the same day and some the next day.

I don't see a correlation with the updates... so why did it start on all the computers (I checked about 12 of them) on about the same day (all the users say earlier this week)?

Comment: What recent updates have been installed? What happened most recently prior to the problem occurring? You can't ask us if an update caused this without noting the updates installed.

Comment: @music2myear Sorry, I mentioned the build and I thought that was enough. I edited the question now.

Comment: Same thing was happening for me on x64, using the Office 365 "First Release" channel, but was resolved yesterday with an update.  Not sure how long the update had been pending - I forced a check-for-updates from within Excel.